# How to check InputStream is empty in context of generating CRL?

Tags: java, x509

Given CRL url, I want to retrieve X509CRL Object. The following are the code,

```
    private static X509CRL downloadCRLFromWeb(String crlURL) throws
            MalformedURLException, IOException, CertificateException, CRLException {

        URL url = new URL(crlURL);
        InputStream crlStream = url.openStream();
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            return (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(crlStream);
        } catch (CRLException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            assert crlStream != null;
            crlStream.close();
        }
```

The line `return (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(crlStream);` would generate `CRLException: Empty input` on some urls I've tried(not all).

The following is the stacktrace,

```
java.security.cert.CRLException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCRL(X509Factory.java:397)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCRL(CertificateFactory.java:497)
    at demo.pkcs.pkcs11.TryLDAP.downloadCRLFromWeb(TryLDAP.java:60)
    at demo.pkcs.pkcs11.TryLDAP.main(TryLDAP.java:83)
```

It's also noted that `crlStream` does not return `-1` when it's read, hence it's not exactly 'empty'. What exactly caused this exception and how can I solve it? And how can I correct this code so that I can retrieve `X509CRL` Object from urls that I get this exception from?

Comment: In this context 'empty' really means (1) it doesn't look like binary 'DER' i.e. doesn't have first byte 0x30 and (2) `X509Factory` searched for a PEM 'begin' line and didn't find one. Look at the actual data received and determine what is wrong with it (or with the URL), or post it in unambiguous form (like hex or `cat -vET`) for others to look at, or give us real, public URL(s) to look at.

Comment: Read to buffer first - you can do with the buffer whatever you want.

Comment: Why check it at all, when you already have an exception being thrown and caught? Either way it means no CRL.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank u for your explanation, it really helps. I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For urls that I've caught the exception from, I've resolved with the following steps:

1. Convert `crlStream` into `String` object
2. Add `"-----BEGIN X509CRL-----\n"` and `"\n-----END X509CRL-----\n"` at the start and the end of `crlStreamString`
3. Convert `crlStreamString` back into `InputStream`

Below are the working code,

```
        InputStream crlStream = url.openStream();
        String stream = IOUtils.toString(crlStream);
        String tryPEM = "-----BEGIN X509CRL-----\n";
        tryPEM = tryPEM.concat(stream);
        tryPEM = tryPEM.concat("\n-----END X509CRL-----\n");
        System.out.println(tryPEM);
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            return (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(IOUtils.toInputStream(tryPEM));
```